# React Native WebView Navigation

Tags: react-native

I am using

```
const newURL = 'https://www.google.com/';
const redirectTo = 'window.location = "' + newURL + '"';
this.webview.injectJavaScript(redirectTo);
```

to navigate.

Is there any other way to do this since my web app is reloading every time I do a window.location and web app state is vanished.

Kind regards!

Comment: You can use a state variable to store the URL and pass it to the webview

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain it a little bit?

Comment: Create a state variable like `const [url,setUrl] = useState("https://www.google.com/")`  and then inside your webview  set the URL as the source. `<WebView source={{ uri: url }} />`. the use `setUrl` to change the URL whenever you want (example : on a button press).I've assumed you are using functional components/

Comment: where to create the const ... = useState ?

Comment: if you are using class-based component, use `state` variable and add a new entry to it. then update the value using `setState`. If you can share more code. I can help.

Comment: Can you update the question with the new code?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the constructor method inside your class component, add a new property to state for `url`.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { url: "https://www.google.com/" };
  }
```

Then update your webview source to use the new state variable as the source.

```
<WebView source={{ uri: this.state.url }} />
<Button onPress={this.buttonPressEvent} />
```

Then whenever you want to change the url,

```
  buttonPressEvent = (event) => {
    //set new url here.
    this.setState({ url: 'https://facebook.com' });
  }
```

Comment: Great! But the Web App is still reloading completely.

Comment: Yes, it will reload and navigate to the new URL. you want to navigate back and forth in webview history?